# How to encode # character in the url + php + Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I am trying to fetch a variable address from my current URL using `JRequest::getVar('address')` method.
But if the address value has a (#) character, the part after the # character is not retrieved.

I understand that URI is a combination of query + fragment and the part after a hash symbol is treated as a fragment.
I have tried to use urlencode method but it still doesn't solve the problem.

Can anyone please tell me how to solve the issue?

Comment: I had the same issue, and found that double encoding it (%2523) seemed to work better. But still not satisfied, so I will be looking further..
Update: it just occurred to me that the value I was encoding is passed to the PHP file via mod_rewrite. See also: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html, search for "Extended Redirection".
irc#httpd states that '#' is simply not a valid path/uri component period >.<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you will have to replace the hash-symbol on your own. For example:

```
str_replace($the_url, '#', '-');
```

I don't know, where exactly you have to do that, because I don't know how the Joomla!-Framework handles links and urls. But I am sure, that someone else can help here any further...

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a good solution. The values are entered by the user and to show him the same value, I will have to first replace the '#' symbol with another symbol and then again replace the other symbol with # for each field using str_replace('-', '#' JRequest::getVar('parameter')).

I know this would work but is there any better method?

Answer (score 6):

What is the problem with using `urlencode`? It should replace `#` with `%23` and all should be well. You can try `JRequest::getVar(str_replace('#', '%23', 'address'))` which should do the trick. Can you post an example URL that doesn't get properly `urlencode`d?

Comment: 'http://test.com/index.php?ADDRESS=101 Street #6 City'

The part after # is treated as a fragment (even after urlencoding)

Comment: I just urlencoded that exact URL and it is properly escape for me. What happens when you execute this code in your version of PHP?

`<?php echo(urlencode('test.com/index.php?ADDRESS=101 Street #6 City')); ?>`

Comment: (I get `test.com%2Findex.php%3FADDRESS%3D101+Street+%236+City`)

Comment: You get a properly encoded url. But when you try to retrieve a 'get' parameter as JRequest::getVar('ADDRESS'), the part after # is truncated because I guess, # is a fragment identifier.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Ah, ok. If this is a URL you're generating for your application, then you probably only want to `urlencode` the part after the `?`. Try `'http://test.com/index.php?'.urlencode('ADDRESS=101 Street #6 City')`.

Comment: Just a note that I downloaded Joomla and poked through the code of `JRequest`. It looks like all it's doing is pulling the value from `$_REQUEST`. I tried dumping `$_REQUEST` in a PHP script which has the  `urlencode`d parameter above and it seems to pick it up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Encode the Hash in the URL with a %23 replacement

```
http://twitter.com/home?status=I+believe+in+%23love
```

"I believe in #love"

Answer (score 0):

The part after # is never sent to Apache/PHP, and can therefore not be retrieved by a PHP script. What you need to do, is to url encode the ADDRESS parameter of the URL.

```
test.com/index.php?ADDRESS=<?= urlencode('101 Street #6 City') ?>
```

That code will generate the following url

```
test.com/index.php?ADDRESS=101+Street+%236+City
```

Now on this URL, you can retrieve address with `JRequest::getVar('ADDRESS')`

Comment: Even after urlencoding the address, I cannot retrieve the address with JRequest::getVar('ADDRESS')

Here lies the problem. %23 also does not serve the purpose.

Comment: What do you get when you `var_dump($_GET);die;`?

Comment: Maybe Joomla! is translating this back into `#` internally. So that you don't get the intended result...

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Joomla doc](http://docs.joomla.org/JURI) out. You can retrieve what Joomla call the 'fragment' by doing:

```
$uri = 'http://fredbloggs:itsasecret@www.example.com:8080/path/to/Joomla/index.php?task=view&id=32#anchorthis';
$u =& JURI::getInstance( $uri );
echo 'Fragment is ' . $u->getFragment();
```